# Daily Deal Website- Content Management System?

Tags: content-management-system

My client is looking to build a website similar to woot.com, is there an API that would be recommended to use or should it be built from scratch?

Comment: Since woot is pretty unique, I'm guessing you'll need to start from the ground and build up. That doesn't mean you could not incorporate elements of other systems and build a good site.

Comment: Any suggestions for the Daily Deal section.  How would you suggest to have it be managed on the backend?  Any particular API

Comment: I was wondering that myself, if there is any "good" extensible open source DOD (deal of day) apps out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [vibrantOS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vibrantos/) in PHP - it's a basic deal-a-day project, but looks extensible.